# Regression with categorical variables only?

Tags: regression, self-study, ordinal-data

I am really new to statistics and currently I am doing some exercises, but I have a problem.

I have a dataset with a column of nationality, coded as either 1 or 2 (UK or International citizen). Then I have 3 more columns with preferences regarding three restaurants, which are coded from 1 to 5 (that is a categorical variable, right?), as 5 being the most favorite.

What kind of analysis you suggest in order to determine whether being UK determines the favorability of a certain place. In other words, I want to see whether nationality affects facility preferences?

Comment: Your variables encoding preferences are not just categorical. They are actually *ordinal*. You can start with a simple ordinal regression and then move forward from there. Look up also the terms `Likert Scale`; the analysis techniques presented for Likert variables are something you might want to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable with preferences regarding a certain restaurant (1--5) is clearly ordinal, so you should look into ordinal regression.

There are many posts on this site, some:

- [Ordinal regression vs. summated score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/ordinal-regression-vs-summated-score)
- [Analysis for ordinal categorical outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome)

... links therein, and search this site