# What test is appropriate for my data set?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, survey, ordinal-data

So my data is on feedback students receive during their 4 years at university. I sent out a questionnaire and there are 23 questions in total, each question is looking at the perception and value of feedback. For each question the students select once answer: either strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree or strongly disagree.

So there are 4 years in terms of students: year 1, year 2, year 3 and year 4. 
I'm trying to find whether there is a difference in their responses for each question. I was going to use chi square but since I have 4 groups to analyze I want to know what statistics would be best suited for this data.

So questions include: 
e.g. q5 the feedback is given in a timely manner: select one of the following strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree or strongly disagree.

e.g. q8 feedback I receive is relevant to my goals as an undergrad:   select one of the following strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree or strongly disagree.

Comment: Are all 23 of the questions assumed to be measuring the same construct?

Comment: Yes all 23 questions are measuring the same construct.

Answer (score 0):

Your response scale

> strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree or strongly disagree

is ordinal, so you should look into ordinal regression. A chi-squared test, in comparison, will not use the ordering in the scale, so will give a less powerful test. There are many posts here about ordinal regression, so search the site. Some starting points:

- [Interpretation of ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89474/interpretation-of-ordinal-logistic-regression)
- [Analysis for ordinal categorical outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome)
- [Ordinal regression vs. summated score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/ordinal-regression-vs-summated-score)