# Regression with maximum value for the output variable? (Clinical score)

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, medicine

I am trying to regression an output variable which has a set maximum value (say 100). But when I try to predict it (using both linear and non-linear regression), the predicted values are sometimes greater than 100.

Is there a way to constraint that my predictions are less than or equal to 100 (other than the simple idea of converting the predicted values greater than 100 to 100?).

Comment: What is your outcome variable and why should it not exceed 100? This will determine the most appropriate approach.

Comment: My output variable is a clinical score. But for argument sake, it can even be the total marks in a final exam where the maximum marks is 100.

Comment: Consider using beta regression after converting to a 0-1 range.  See eg https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/ERCIM-2010.pdf

Comment: @BigBendRegion, Thanks a lot. Will give beta regression a go!!

Answer (score 0):

Your outcome variable, a clinical score, seems to be an ordinal variable. So try ordinal regression. See [Ordinal regression vs. summated score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/ordinal-regression-vs-summated-score) or [Analysis for ordinal categorical outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome),  and search this site.

Comment: See also [this](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) for ordinal regression resources.